# Adding ID to a Listing but not inside WP_Query while

Tags: php, functions

```
    <?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'bedrijf',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
          );
          $query = new WP_Query( $args );
          if ( $query->have_posts()) :
            while ( $query->have_posts()) :  $query->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $beginletter = substr(strtoupper($title), 0,1); ?>

        <li id="list" data-filter="<?php foreach ($terms as $term){ echo $term->term_taxonomy_id; } ?>" data-letter="<?php echo $beginletter; ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
```

MAJOR EDIT:
So I fixed a few issues and I have a new problem, what happens now is it shows the same ID as from the same result on ALL post types. I know it's because of the while but I don't know how to put data-filter inside the li but outside the while? Or any other solution to this perhaps?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I have two queries and they would override eachother. So I thought that if I had a global function that all I had to do was place `echo $term->name;` anywhere or am I wrong?

Comment: I still have no idea what you are doing. If you are in your `foreach` loop then `$term` is an object and echoing `$term->name` will echo out that term's name. What is the point of $terms and $terms2?

Comment: Oh my bad the `$term2` was to be ignored it was only to try something out. The main issue is that I have a listing in a wp_query while and I need to have `$term->name` in the listing now I thought that a function would help so that I won't disturb the `wp_query`

Comment: I could add the entire code if that helps?

Comment: It might, but I still think you need to try to explain what you are doing. Two queries that override each other? To what purpose? Right now I see a basic foreach loop that doesn't have anything wrong with it.

Comment: I changed it I hope I was specific enough this time if not, please do tell and i'll try and change it again.

Comment: I can't see how the code you've posted should conflict. Nothing should "override" anything. You have to provide a better explanation of the issue and I would suggest supplying copy/paste-able code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I don't think anybody here understands what the code you want is supposed to do, the question is unclear. Can you please state what the function would do without using the word override, or using code references

Comment: I did. If I were to place `echo $term->name;` outside the foreach above at the place where I wrote `HERE` It would not give me all the results even if I wrote `data-filter="<?php foreach ($terms2 as $termss){ echo $termss->term_id; } ?>"` instead it gives me 2 of about 6 terms that are selected in the first post name and it repeats it for all of the other post names while some of them have different terms selected for themselves.

Comment: I edited and pasted the issue there for better overview.

Comment: If you use `data-filter="<?php foreach($terms2 as $termss){echo $termss->term_id;} ?>"` you will get something like this because it will combine all the numbers in one line. `data-filter="123456789"` - what exactly are you trying to accomplish? You might want to use [wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) so you can actually put the posts term IDs into that filter field, but even then you should probably only use 1 `term_id` per filter field.

Comment: Well all in all I want to make a filter and my idea was to use either all the term names as connection with the list of terms i have with checkboxes OR the id indeed but if i'm not wrong say you select 4 terms for a post shouldn't you then get 4 id's? That's why I thought the name would be better but I could also be wrong.

Comment: In fact what happens is it pastes only 2 of the 5 selected term id's of the post, I'm wondering why it doesn't do all of them.. As well as the exact reason why I thought I needed a function because it places the 2 id's that I get onto EVERY post name while they don't have that term. I'm guessing it's due to the While of WP_Query.

Comment: So you just want to list all the term IDs in the data-filter attribute?

Comment: Yes but I edited my post, my new issue is that the first result appears in all post names data-filters. Pretty sure it's due to the while.